# extract all metadata which was created or changed

Tags: deployment, metadata, package.xml

i need to provide a package.xml file that explicitly lists all contents / metadata that got created or changed in dev sandbox.
are there any tools that can simplify this task.
does anything need to be done to exclude artifacts related to installed packages.

Comment: i used this and found helpful in preparing package.xml file : https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use eclipse(force.com IDE) for getting the whole package of that org as well as package.xml is a easiest way to get the package.xml.

Comment: i have just setup Force.com IDE and created a new project. but my package.xml file which got created while creating project only contains entries like :    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types> How to get classes which our team created.

Comment: Yes Package.xml contains only xml notation. You need to go to the class folder in the same package to see the classes which you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Since you specifically asked for a tool, and we offer a free 30 day trial, I don't feel too spammy by suggesting you use Gearset which is a service my team and I have built to simplify release management for Salesforce.

For your use case, you can do a comparison between your dev sandbox and production, and then export that to Excel. It is free, will take you a few minutes, and then you need never use it again if you don't want the other features :)

Get started at [gearset.com](https://gearset.com)

Answer (score 0):

Walker,
There is no way to specifically query for only the changed items using the metadata API (which generates or uses the package.xml file). You will have to figure out the differences manually. As previous posters said, you have to use some tool to figure out the differences and then construct the package.xml file.

There are various tools that make that process easy and my company, DreamFactory, provides a product called SnapShot that help you with that as well. Free 14 day trial, free support during trial, admin friendly.

Take a look and let me know if you have any followup questions.

Good luck.

Sridhar